# MongoDB - What's the best practice to store sub documents?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB. I have a question regarding best practice for storing sub documents. Let's say that I have a User model. And then later on, I need to add payment history (1 user can have multiple payment history). In the terms of performance, which one would be better?

1. Adding payment history data directly to user model

User model:

```
{
  '_id' : 1,
  'name' : 'John',
  'payment_history' : [
    {
      'payment_date' : '2020-05-15T00:00:00Z',
      'desc' : '30-day Sub',
      'payment_method' : 'Paypal'
    }
  ]
}
```

or

2. Make a separate payment history model, user model saving only the payment id

User model:

```
{
  '_id' : 1,
  'name' : 'John',
  'payment_history' : [
      12345
  ]
}
```

Payment history model:

```
{
   '_payment_id' : 12345,
   'payment_date' : '2020-05-15T00:00:00Z',
   'desc' : '30-day Sub',
   'payment_method' : 'Paypal'
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is about data modeling. You have this question - to resolve this you need to know how your application uses this data - in CRUD operations. Generally, the most important queries need to be taken into account. Then there are other factors like size of document, the number of documents, the query performance, etc. Also, see [Data Model Design](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/).

Answer (score 0):

data

```
db={
  "user": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "John"
    }
  ],
  "payment": [
    {
      "_payment_id": 12345,
      "_user_id": 1,
      "payment_date": "2020-05-15T00:00:00Z",
      "desc": "30-day Sub",
      "payment_method": "Paypal"
    }
  ]
}
```

aggregate

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "payment",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "_user_id",
      "as": "payment_docs"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KeVOEKyYbjI)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define what performance means for your app.
If the most frequent or critical query needs User+Payments then you better embed *some* payment information, just the fields needed to avoid `$lookup` or extra queries, and usually it makes sense to store only the last N payments.